updating a date string in a specified format
I have a time stamp column which stores the date in the below format
12-JUN-24 09.02.32.000000000 AM
I want to update the time for that column and used the below query
update tablename
set date_column =
      TO_DATE('12-JUN-24 09.04.32.000000000 AM', 'DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS.sssssssss AM')
WHERE #conditon#

but I am getting

ORA-01810 format code appears twice error

what is the correct format to provide for the above query if I am going to use
TO_DATE() or TO_TIMESTAMP() functions in my query
can you help me with examples of using time stamp with AM/PM and without them.

Dates are stored in databases as integers. They have no format. Formatting is done in the presentation layer.

Oracle dates to not have fractional seconds, so you can't supply those to_date(); and your format model doesn't include the date parts; and the format model for fractional seconds is ff, not sssssssss. (See the documentation for descriptions of the format elements.) It's seeing that sssssssss as repeating the ss seconds element, hence the specific error you're seeing now.
As you want to end up with a timestamp you just need to use the right function and format:
update tablename
set date_column=TO_TIMESTAMP('12-JUN-24 09.04.32.000000000 AM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')
WHERE #conditon#

Or more simply here, use a timestamp literal:
update tablename
set date_column=TIMESTAMP '2024-06-12 09:04:32'
WHERE #conditon#

Either way the value actually stored in the database is the same. It is stored in Oracle's internal representation, the details of which you generally don't need to know. When you query your table your client (or application) will format it; clients will generally use your session's NLS settings by default - NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT here, which seems to be set to the format string I used in the first update statement above.
If you want to see the stored value in a particular format then you could change your NLS settings, but it's better to not rely on those. Instead use to_char() with the format you want:
select to_char(date_column, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3') as date_column
from tablename
where #conditon#

or
select to_char(date_column, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') as date_column
from tablename
where #conditon#

fiddle
I've included the 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH' in that, and the first update, to control the language used to display the month abbreviation; another reason I prefer ISO *8-)

I updated my query to include the date part which I had missed in my question

OK, but the rest applies. And be careful using YY vs RR - the documentation I linked to has a discussion. Really I would avoid using 2-digit years anywhere anyway; the defaults in Oracle tools still seem to use RR but really there's no reason not to use YYYY (or RRRR) when you format a date or timestamp as a string, to avoid any confusion about which year you meant. I prefer the ISO-8604 formats for the same reason.

Thank you this helped. When I tried SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(12-JUN-24 09.04.32.000000000','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF) FROM DUAL ,it returned 12-JUN-24 09.04.32.000000000 PM,is there any way to display the time in 24 hour format,I also tried HH24 in the query,but it returned the time stamp appended with AM/PM

You need to format the timestamp value as a string,; updated to show to_char() being used.
